# deploying ruby on rails applications on solaris 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solaris

Is there anyone out there that is currently deploying rails applications on a solaris 10 box? If so can you give me a brief run down of what you had to do to get it up and going?

I am a web developer and I am working in a closed environment where they are using sun solaris servers, all of which are for internal use only behind firewall. I am by no means a solaris admin type and the solaris admin type here have no knowledge, nor the care to learn, of ruby/rails.

I have had no issue getting ruby on rails development environments up and running in OS/X, Linux(OpenSuse, Ubuntu, Fedora), and Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This SO question has a nice detailed answer on what packages are needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145468/anyone-installed-rails-3-on-solaris-10x86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Phusion's Passenger](http://modrails.com) module for Apache 2 supports Solaris.

There's a tutorial written by [Johannes Fahrenkrug](http://www.springenwerk.com) from March 2009 which covers [deploying Ruby on Rails to Solaris 10 with Passenger and Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.springenwerk.com/2009/03/passenger-and-ruby-enterprise-edition.html).

There's also [this article](http://www.cubiclemuses.com/cm/articles/2009/04/09/rails-passenger-open-solaris-ec2/) which discusses deploying to Open Solaris. Whilst Open Solaris and Solaris are not the same beast, it might have some pointers you need.

Comment: The sun box I am running on is not up to 5/08 release, but this was very helpful and I am going to try to get the sys adm to update to 5/08 so i can follow these instructions thanks