# Anyone installed rails 3 on solaris 10x86

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, solaris

I would like an easy way of installing Rails 3 on  Solaris 10 x86 server that is not attached to the internet. I can download files and burn to DVD or mem stick and install that way. Some Packages would be best as not really looking forward to compiling from source.

Has anyone done this or seen any guides releating on how to do this ?  I have seen an old post (2009) but that doesn't really help me.

Regards
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need to install all the requirements for running Ruby and RoR 3.0.

It's easiest to get everything from [Sun Freeware](http://www.sunfreeware.com)

### Dependencies

You'll need to install these dependencies for RoR first.

- **Ruby 1.9.2** - ftp://ftp.sunfreeware.com/pub/freeware/intel/10/ruby-1.9.2p0-sol10-x86-local.gz

  - Do not get Ruby 1.9.1 from that page - the warning is that you can't use 1.9.1 with Rails 3.0.

Portions of the Ruby package might need to depend on the following packages, some of which should already be installed by default on Solaris 10 (like zlib, libiconv, and libintl), but I haven't touched a base Solaris machine in a while so you might need to download everything to be sure:

- **OpenSSL** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#openssl098

  - also depends on libgcc_s.so.1
- **gdbm** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#gdbm
- **libiconv** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#libiconv

  - depends on libintl and libgcc_s.so.1 below
- **libintl** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#libintl

  - depends on libgcc_s.so.1 below
- **ncurses** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#ncurses

  - depends on libintl and libiconv above, and libgcc_s.so.1
- **libedit** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#libedit

  - depends on libgcc_s.so.1 below
- **tcl** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#tcl

  - depends on tk and libgcc_s.so.1 below
- **tk** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#tk

  - depends on xft, xrender, expat, fontconfig, libiconv, libintl, freetype, zlib, libgcc_s.so.1
- **zlib** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#zlib

  - depends on libgcc_s.so.1
- **xft** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#xft

  - depends on fontconfig, freetype, zlib, xrender, render, expat
- **render** - ftp://ftp.sunfreeware.com/pub/freeware/intel/10/render-0.8-sol10-intel-local.gz
- **xrender** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#xrender
- **berkely db** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#db47

  - depends on libgcc_s.so.1
- **fontconfig** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#fontconfig

  - depends on freetype, zlib, expat, libiconv, libgcc_s.so.1
- **freetype** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#freetype

  - depends on zlib, and libgcc_s.so.1
- **expat** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#expat

  - depends on libgcc_s.so.1
- **libgcc_so.so.1** has to be in /usr/local/lib, so you need to install either of:

  - **libgcc 3.4.6** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#libgcc34
  - **gcc 3.4.6** - http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#gcc34

---

### Installing the packages

The packages from Sun Freeware can be installed with the `pkgadd` tool in Solaris 10: http://www.sunfreeware.com/download.html

Example:

> To install a file you have downloaded, follow the example here: For example, if you were to download a gzipped package foo-1.00-sol8-sparc-local.gz into directory /tmp, to install this package, you would use the following commands:

```
cd /tmp
gunzip foo-1.00-sol8-sparc-local.gz
pkgadd -d foo-1.00-sol8-sparc-local
```

---

### Install RoR 3

That's just everything to get Ruby running. Now you have to [download RoR source and build it](http://rubyonrails.org/download)

---

### Might be easier (?)

You might be able to ease this process of dependency getting by attempting to use the pkg-get script from bolthole: http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/pkg-get.html

The script allows you to run a Download-only mode to get packages. I don't think it requires you to run it on a solaris machine if you use download-only mode, but otherwise you might be able to hack it up a little just to download and not care about installed packages and such.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'll go and check it out.

Comment: I don't think this is a bare-bones list. Why do you need `render` and `freetype`? Are you using imagemagick or some other server-based graphics rendering?

Comment: @David This is the bare-minimum list for every single dependency of Ruby listed on OpenCSW/Sun Freeware. `render` and `freetype` are needed by TCL/TK, which is a Ruby dependency. It is unnecessary if you don't need to use the Ruby tcl/tk extension, but a thorough dependency list was better in this case where he was going to download packages and install them offline.